# Error publishing and scanning the IdUser in Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder () .setId1 (sysid) .setId2 (IdUser) Android Beacon Library

Tags: android, beacon

Hello friends I have an error with beacon, it turns out that when I transmit my beacon from my cell phone I expose a UserId so that later it can be detected by another device and I can identify it for this UserId pass it in the following code:

```
String IdUser="23";

public void startBroadcast(String sysid,String IdUser) {
        Log.d(TAG, "comenzando la función de transmisión");
        Log.d("startBroadcast", "comenzando la función de transmisión"+IdUser);
        Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
                .setId1(sysid)
                .setId2(IdUser)
                .setManufacturer(0x0118) // Radius Networks.  Change this for other beacon layouts
                .setTxPower(-59)
                .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[]{0l})) // Remove this for beacon layouts without d: fields
                .build();
        // Change the layout below for other beacon types
        BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
                .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT);
        beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);

        beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Fallo al pubicar erro en el codigo: " + errorCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Inicio del anuncio exitoso.");
                Log.d(TAG, settingsInEffect.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

When I scan and try to detect the device I get a strange UserId => firstBeacon.getId2()=>"0x00000000000c"

this is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {

        RangeNotifier rangeNotifier = new RangeNotifier() {
            @Override
            public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
                double distancia = 0;
                if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "DidRangeBeaconsInRegion contando cercanias:" + beacons.size());
                    Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                    String beaconLog = "Primera cercania" + firstBeacon.toString() + " es " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " A metros de distancia.";
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(firstBeacon.getId1()));
                    String beaconID = String.valueOf(firstBeacon.getId1());
                    String beaconID2 = String.valueOf(firstBeacon.getId2());
                    
                    Log.d(TAG, beaconLog);

                    if (distancia < 0.01) {
                        Log.d("Evento", "Distance");
                        
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("AVISO", "NO EXISTE APROXIMACIONES");

                }
            }

        };
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
            beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
            beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(rangeNotifier);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
        }
    }
```

I would like you to return the UserID number, I do not understand what I am doing wrong please help
this is the library link: https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "strange" value 0x00000000000c is a Java string showing Hexadecimal representation of an Eddystone-UID instance identifier (the library returns this as `getId2()` because this is the second most significant identifier in the Eddystone-UID format.)  Because the Eddystone-UID instance identifier is 6 bytes long, it won't fit into a Java integer.  So the library converts it to a default string representation represented as hexadecimal.

For your use case, what you want is to discard the most significant bytes of the identifier, convert it to an integer, and then back to a string:

```
String id2AsDecimal = 
  new Integer(Integer.parseInt(firstBeacon.getId2().substring(6), 16)).toString() // "12"
```

In your test case, the code above would return "12"

EDIT:  The code above limits your id2 to be six hex digits -- 0 to 0xFFFFFF (0 to 16777215 decimal)  because that is the maximum number of hex digits a Java Integer can entirely hold.

To get more digits, you can also use Long.parseLong(...) to get 12 hex digits.  Beyond that you need more sophisticated parsing or data types that can hold numbers larger then a Long.